# SQL SELECT NON ALPHABETIC ACCOUNTS

Tags: sql

I am running this a query to select only non alphanumeric accounts but they keep appearing. I want an exact return so I don't want to use Like
the accounts on the DB are like

```
( 012450012152200, 01R4500000125,01L55001252022)
```

this is my Query

```
SELECT * FROM @Employee WHERE Substring(Account_Number,3,1) != '[^a-zA-Z]'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: do you want to select non alphanumeric or non alphabetic, title and content are different.

Comment: `WHERE Substring(Account_Number, 3, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'`

Comment: I am wondering if you are misunderstanding 'like'? What do you mean by 'an exact return?' 'Like' is not the same as a fuzzy search, if that is what you are thinking...

Comment: Most DBMS have different operators for pattern matching using regex.  Postgtres uses ~ or ~*. Oracle has a suite of functions including regexp_like.

Comment: And I wonder why you're trying to do this? Does it matter if an Account_Number includes letters or not?!? That's a bad design...